# How to interpret zigzag training loss?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, loss-function

My training data consists of about ~700 unique samples (this is for a regression problem). The data is not shuffled, so the first N samples have the same label (say, the value *1.25*), then the next M samples have a the same label (say, *2.99*), etc. In total there's around 15 unique labels.

I'm using a simple CNN, as the input is an image (64x64x3). Even with no dropout or any other form of regularization, I can't get the training loss to stabilize close to zero.

[image]

What is this pattern of the learning loss an indication of? (gray line is the training loss, orange line is the validation loss).

Answer (score 2):

The only indication you can get from such pattern is that the learning rate is too large, you should decrease it until the loss starts to decrease.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that your learning rate is
>   too large, making your parameters oscillate wildly.

Things that I recommend at that point would be to:

- Decrease your initial learning rate
- Try another optimizer with some sort of learning rate decay (e.g. ADAM which worked good for me in such cases)